# How to add selected row from datagrid to database?

Tags: c#, wpf, database, entity-framework

I have a database with three tables.
Also I have a datagrid which shows several properties of two entities(tables).
To select information from both tables I use a stored procedure which works fine.
I want to select a row in this datagrid and by pressing a button this will be added into the third table in database. And another button should be for showing the whole information (all properties) of the entities. 
I don't know what to do with X after ChosenBooksAuthors - it should be BookID insted of X but I can't reach it, what should I do? How to add selected row into a table?
XAML:

```
<Canvas>
<DataGrid CanUserAddRows="False" x:Name="Info" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=ChosenBooksAuthors}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Bookslist}" Background="Honeydew" Canvas.Top="190" Canvas.Left="38" Width="297" Height="105" ></DataGrid>
</Canvas>
```

C#:

```
 private List<Book> _VMBooksAuthors = new List<Book>();

            public List<Book> ChosenBooksAuthors
            {
                get
                {
                    return _VMBooksAuthors;
                }
                set
                {
                    _VMBooksAuthors = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("ChosenBooksAuthors");
                }
            }
        private void BasketButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
                Basket b = db1.BasketSet.Where(c => c.BookID == ChosenBooksAuthors.X).FirstOrDefault();
                db1.BasketSet.Add(b);
                db1.SaveChanges();


            }
```

Answer (score 1):

ChosenBooksAuthors is a collection, selected item should be Book. Try:

```
<DataGrid CanUserAddRows="False" x:Name="Info" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=Book}" ...
```

Or just cast:

```
private void BasketButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var book = (Book)myDataGrid.SelectedItem;
    Basket b = db1.BasketSet.FirstOrDefault(c => c.BookID == book.BookID);  // No need for where with FirstOrDefault()
    db1.BasketSet.Add(b);
    db1.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: If I check it with a checkpoint, then I see that in  db1.BasketSet.Add(b); b=null
but in a previous row it had needed properties

Comment: now everyting is okay and all data present but when i write this: db1.SaveChanges();
it throws 
System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException

Comment: Check the inner exception for the message. Could be you are trying to add a key that exists or are missing a required field.